# GLIBCXX_3.4.15 not found

Tags: wubi, blender, glibc

When I try to run Blender builds from Graphicall.org (11.04 Natty 64-bit), I get the following message:

```
./blender: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./blender)
```

I have tried updating GCC and G++, but it still gives the error, and when I run

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC
```

I get

```
GLIBCXX_3.4 
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.3.4
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

Are there any other libraries needed to get glib 3.4.15 on 11.04, or any other workarounds?

Edit: I don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm on a Wubi install.

`ldd ./blender` gives

```
./blender: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./blender)
            linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffce5ff000)
            libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f773ec3d000)
            libpython3.2mu.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/libpython3.2mu.so.1.0 (0x00007f773e6cc000)
            libopenal.so.1 => /usr/lib/libopenal.so.1 (0x00007f773e473000)
            libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f773e265000)
            libtiff.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4 (0x00007f773e002000)
            libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f773dde9000)
            libsndfile.so.1 => /usr/lib/libsndfile.so.1 (0x00007f773db81000)
            libfftw3.so.3 => /usr/lib/libfftw3.so.3 (0x00007f773d886000)
            libSDL-1.2.so.0 => /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0 (0x00007f773d5ef000)
            libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f773d372000)
            libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007f773d103000)
            libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f773cdc8000)
            libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f773cbb8000)
            libjpeg.so.62 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62 (0x00007f773c994000)
            libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f773c76c000)
            libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f773c3d7000)
            libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f773c152000)
            libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f773bf4d000)
            libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f773bd2f000)
            libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f773ba29000)
            libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f773b812000)
            libssl.so.0.9.8 => /lib/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0x00007f773b5bf000)
            libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0x00007f773b230000)
            libffi.so.5 => /usr/lib/libffi.so.5 (0x00007f773b027000)
            libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f773adfd000)
            libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f773abfa000)
            librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f773a9f1000)
            libFLAC.so.8 => /usr/lib/libFLAC.so.8 (0x00007f773a7a7000)
            libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007f773a2d8000)
            libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007f773a0ab000)
            libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/libogg.so.0 (0x00007f7739ea4000)
            libpulse-simple.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpulse-simple.so.0 (0x00007f7739ca0000)
            libpulse.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpulse.so.0 (0x00007f7739a5e000)
            libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f773984c000)
            libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f7739649000)
            libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f7739442000)
            libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f773923c000)
            libdrm.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f7739031000)
            lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f773eefe000)
            libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f7738e14000)
            libpulsecommon-0.9.22.so => /usr/lib/libpulsecommon-0.9.22.so (0x00007f7738bc8000)
            libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f77389c5000)
            libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f77387aa000)
            libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f77385a2000)
            libXtst.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXtst.so.6 (0x00007f773839b000)
            libxcb-atom.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb-atom.so.1 (0x00007f7738196000)
            libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f7737f52000)
            libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f7737d4e000)
            libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f7737b48000)
            libwrap.so.0 => /lib/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007f773793d000)
            libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f7737737000)
            libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f773751d000)
```

Comment: post the output of `ldd ./blender`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

optionally you can force a global update of all the linked libraries with

```
sudo ldconfig
```

this last command can take some time and will not print anything on the bash, just wait.

EDIT

considering all the informations that you gave to us, you need to update your stdc++ library, this is the output of the same command that you used on your machine, but running on another machine updated to the latest stdc++ from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test)

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.3.4
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

to get that executable running you have to stay up to date with your std library.

**Instructions**

about how to update your stdc++ libraries from this PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

now your stdc++ should be up to date, this PPA also contains some others c++ libraries that are probably not already installed in your system, you can use a package manager to filter all the `libstdc++` packages.

Comment: I tried both of those; it tells me libstdc++6 is already the newest version, and ldconfig finishes in about a second and doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: ok, let's find how many stdc++ libraries do you have installed and where. run `locate libstdc++.so.6` and post the output.

Comment: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.14`
`/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6`
`/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.14`

Comment: the libraries looks ok for the linker, and all the packages looks ok too, the only question left is something about a specific libstdc++ version that is required to run this executable. If you want to update the C++ libraries you have to use an external PPA because this are bleeding-edge packages that can arm your system and are supposed to be used only by developers, take a look at http://superuser.com/a/394811 and just update the system, in your case you just have to update the libraries.

Comment: how exactly would I update the libraries?

Comment: @AnthonyP i will add this information in my first post, wait until you see it.

Answer (score 3):

What I found was that adding `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` worked for me.

**EDIT:** `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is an environment variable which can be set by the command `export`.