# How to fix a "/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found" error?

Tags: compiling, c++

I've been getting this annoying problem. I want to compile a `.so` under Ubuntu using the **Anjuta IDE**. It compiles fine and all, but when I load it, that's when the error comes up:

```
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found
```

I've tried everything in [GLIBCXX_3.4.15 not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164296/glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found). But nothing seemed to work.

Comment: If you use a ppa with a newer version of gcc or other packages, it might be a problem in older versions of ubuntu (older than 11.10) because of multiarch. Which ubuntu version do you use? Can you try a live cd of ubuntu 12.04 and see if the problem persists there too? Also, can you post the output of: `dpkg -l gcc* libst* | grep ^ii | awk {'print $2, $3'}`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Here's the output:

`gcc 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5
gcc-4.6 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
gcc-4.6-base 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
gcc-4.7-base 4.7.0-7ubuntu3
libstartup-notification0 0.12-1ubuntu1
libstdc++6 4.7.0-7ubuntu3
libstdc++6-4.6-dev 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
libstlport4.6ldbl 4.6.2-7
`

Also, I'm using version: `ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386`. Running it in a virtual machine on Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Also the output of: `apt-cache policy libstdc++6 libstdc++6-4.6-dev` -- I have ubuntu 12.04 and I don't see a 4.7 version of the libstdc++6 package. Do you use packages from launchpad PPA repositories?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure anymore. I've tried so many things people posted that supposedly would fix this, including installing new packages. ( Lost track of what I've installed, and I'm new with Ubuntu, so yeah ).. Here's the output of that command: ( pasting in pastebin ): [link](http://pastebin.com/JjePatve)

Comment: Well, I would try using a live cd/usb. If it works there, it most definitely is a problem in your installation.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable?

I did and worked.
Let me know if this helps.