# Error starting ICEM CFD: GLIBCXX_3.4.9 not found

Tags: 12.04, glibc

When trying to start ICEMCFD (a meshing tool for flow simulations) I receive an error message and analysing it with `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose` yields:

```
ldzq68@DS-ECSTL-001:/usr/ansys_inc/v121/icemcfd/linux/bin$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose ./icemcfd
ICEM_ACN is /usr/ansys_inc/v121/icemcfd/linux
ANSYSLIC_DIR is set to /usr/ansys_inc/shared_files/licensing
args 
Window information: depth = 24
                    class = 4
visual depth = 24 class = 4
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/r600_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/r600_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/r600_dri.so failed (/usr/ansys_inc/v121/icemcfd/linux/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.1.so.1))
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/r600_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/r600_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/r600_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/r600_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/r600_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/r600_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/r600_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/r600_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/ansys_inc/v121/icemcfd/linux/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.1.so.1))
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Serial number of failed request:  5496
  Current serial number in output stream:  5500
```

After reading other threads I tried updating libstdc++6 and

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

tells me libstdc++6 is already the newest version.

So following [this advice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164296/glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found) I updated my stdc++ libraries using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

but I still receive the same error when I want to start ICEM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I found no such .deb package and I doubt there is one. Just understanding what these files are that the program can't find and how they are generally handled would be a major advance...

Comment: Ah yes, that's actually how I installed it. ICEM comes along with other programs such as Fluent and CFX, all beloning to Ansys. But I could't find any .deb files in the whole package, they're all tar archives.

Comment: Following [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2082431&p=12347678#post12347678) I get `libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory. libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/ldzq68/.drirc: No such file or directory.` But simply renaming the files in the ICEM library as suggested doesn't help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by installing the xfonts-75dpi and xfonts-100dpi libraries after finding [this](http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/ansys-meshing/89147-error-when-starting-icem-cfd-ubuntu.html).